# a user per Apache2 website (Debian)

Tags: debian, apache-httpd, webserver

I have very little experience in Gnu/Linux.

I am now configuring a VPS (Debian 10), on which I want to create more than one, Apache2, virtual host.

All virtual hosts directories will be located in `/var/www/vhosts`.

Accordingly, for each virtual host (e.g. `myproject.com`):

```
/var/www/vhosts/myproject.com
/var/www/vhosts/myproject.com/public_html
/var/www/vhosts/myproject.com/__logs__
```

For each virtual host a new user will be created. For the example above - `usr_myproject`. The home directory (for FTP purposes) of this user should be `/var/www/vhosts/myproject.com` .

My problem is to assign correct permissions and groups for this user and for the virtual host directory. The same question about the `/var/www/vhosts` directory.

Any help or link to web resources will be really appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You question seems to be something about file permissions. What specificaly are you asking about them?

Answer (score 1):

The [ITK](http://mpm-itk.sesse.net/) module for apache2 provides support for having a different system user for each virtual host.   It is packaged for debian as `apache2-mpm-itk`.

It does not create or manage users - that's up to you, using the usual tools.

I used to use this a lot (back when I ran lots of vhosts on a shared server), and I'd usually set it up so that each vhost had its own home directory (`/home/WEB/username`), with `html`, `logs`, `cgi-bin` and everything else related to that vhost under their home directory.  This made it easier to migrate to another server if necessary.

It also made it easier for the vhost's owner to use `ftp` or `sftp` to update their site or fetch their own log files, etc.   And it made sure that the owner of one vhost could not read the files belonging to other vhosts - protecting confidential info like database passwords embedded in scripts or config files.

From the ITK web page:

> apache2-mpm-itk (just mpm-itk for short) is an MPM (Multi-Processing
>   Module) for the Apache web server. mpm-itk allows you to run each of
>   your vhost under a separate uid and gid—in short, the scripts and
>   configuration files for one vhost no longer have to be readable for
>   all the other vhosts.
>
> mpm-itk is based on the traditional prefork MPM, which means it's
>   non-threaded; in short, this means you can run non-thread-aware code
>   (like many PHP extensions) without problems. On the other hand, you
>   lose out to any performance benefit you'd get with threads, of course;
>   you'd have to decide for yourself if that's worth it or not. You will
>   also take an additional performance hit over prefork, since there's an
>   extra fork per request.

and:

> The new configuration settings over the prefork MPM are:
>
> - **AssignUserID**: Takes two parameters, uid and gid (or really, user
>     name and group name; use “#” if you want to specify a raw uid);
>     specifies what uid and gid the vhost will run as (after parsing the
>     request etc., of course). Note that if you do not assign a user ID,
>     the default one from Apache will be used.
> - **AssignUserIDExpr**, **AssignGroupIDExpr** (Apache 2.4 or newer only):
>     Like AssignUserID, but takes in an Apache expression to dynamically
>     choose user or group. See below.
> - **MaxClientsVHost**: A separate MaxClients for the vhost. This can be
>     useful if, say, half of your vhosts depend on some NFS server; if the
>     NFS server goes down, you do not want the children waiting forever on
>     NFS to take the non-NFS-dependent hosts down. This can thus act as a
>     safety measure, giving “server too busy” on the NFS-dependent vhosts
>     while keeping the other ones happily running. (Of course, you could
>     use it to simply keep one site from eating way too much resources, but
>     there are probably better ways of doing that.)
> - **NiceValue**: Lets you nice some requests down, to give them less CPU
>     time.
> - **EnableCapabilities** (Apache 2.4 or newer only): Drop most root
>     capabilities in the parent process, and instead run as the user given
>     by the User/Group directives with some extra capabilities (in
>     particular setuid). Somewhat more secure (especially when coupled with
>     LimitUIDRange above), but can cause problems when serving from
>     filesystems that do not honor capabilities, such as NFS.
> - **LimitUIDRange**, **LimitGIDRange** (Apache 2.4 or newer only): Restrict
>     setuid() and setgid() calls to a given range (e.g. “LimitUIDRange 1000
>     2000" to allow only uids from 1000 to 2000, inclusive), possibly
>     increasing security somewhat. Note that this requires seccomp v2
>     (Linux 3.5.0 or newer). Also, due to technical reasons, setgroups() is
>     not restricted, so a rogue process can still get any group it might
>     want. Still, performing a successful attack will be somewhat trickier
>     than otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You may find file ACLs useful, that way each user can own their own files, but you can use ACLs to allow apache to be able to read them. You may also want to look at default permissions with ACLs.